# Strongswan not all traffic is encrypted

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn, strongswan

I have set up strongswan with Cisco router with following configuration:

```
config setup
    uniqueids=never

ca default_ca
    auto=add

conn %default
    keyexchange=ikev1
    type=tunnel
    left=%any
    auto=add
    dpdaction=clear
    margintime=0s
    rekeyfuzz=20%
conn cisco-ezvpn
    keyexchange=ikev1
    left=10.0.1.2
    leftid=lab
    leftsourceip=%config
    leftfirewall=yes
    right=10.0.1.1
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    xauth_identity=test
    auto=add
    leftauth2=xauth
    xauth=client
    aggressive=yes
    leftauth=psk
    rightauth=psk
    ikelifetime=86000s
    lifetime=86000s
    ike=aes256-sha256-ecp256
    esp=aes256-sha256
```

But I found not all of the traffic is encrypted.

- If some program, such as ssh, already connected to remote server
  before ipsec up, these connections will not be use VPN tunnel, it can
  be see from the tcpdump output:

> [root@lorawan ~]# tcpdump -i eth0  tcpdump: verbose output suppressed,
>   use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on eth0, link-type
>   EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes 22:17:54.407463 IP
>   10.0.1.1 > 10.0.1.2: ESP(spi=0xc0920b53,seq=0x4a), length 184 22:17:59.454819 IP 10.0.1.2 > 10.0.1.1: ESP(spi=0x3ec810fd,seq=0x97),
>   length 120 22:17:59.455637 IP 10.0.1.1 > 10.0.1.2:
>   ESP(spi=0xc0920b53,seq=0x4c), length 104 22:17:59.455637 IP 10.0.1.1 >
>   10.10.0.0: ICMP 10.0.1.1 udp port domain unreachable, length 36 22:17:59.455787 IP 10.0.1.2 > 10.0.1.1: ESP(spi=0x3ec810fd,seq=0x98),
>   length 120 22:18:01.000771 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id
>   8000.80:e0:1d:66:2f:a2.8001, length 43 22:18:03.000814 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8000.80:e0:1d:66:2f:a2.8001, length 43
>   22:18:04.738096 IP 10.0.1.2.33457 > 10.0.1.1.5888: Flags [P.], seq
>   4216930160:4216930182, ack 50432821, win 17584, length 22
>   22:18:04.738618 IP 10.0.1.1.5888 > 10.0.1.2.33457: Flags [.], seq
>   1:27, ack 22, win 3446, length 26 22:18:04.738679 IP 10.0.1.2.33457 >
>   10.0.1.1.5888: Flags [.], ack 27, win 17584, length 0

The default interface: eth0, still can be accessed by outside hosts process, for example, ssh:

> [root@lorawan ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 tcpdump: verbose output suppressed,
>   use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on eth0, link-type
>   EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes 22:24:28.021347 IP
>   10.0.1.2 > 10.0.1.1: ESP(spi=0x3ec810fd,seq=0xa9), length 120 22:24:28.169729 IP 10.0.1.1.36550 > 10.0.1.2.ssh: Flags [P.], seq
>   156:208, ack 825, win 2944, length 52 22:24:28.170144 IP 10.0.1.2.ssh
>
> > 10.0.1.1.36550: Flags [P.], seq 825:893, ack 208, win 16616, length 68 22:24:28.370727 IP 10.0.1.1.36550 > 10.0.1.2.ssh: Flags [.], ack
> >     893, win 2876, length 0

And my iptables forwarder looks OK:

```
[root@lorawan ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.10.0.0            policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 1 proto esp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.10.0.0            policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 1 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  10.10.0.0            anywhere             policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 1 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.10.0.0            anywhere             policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 1 proto esp
```

My question is: Is there any way to route "ALL of the traffic" into VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I think is possible that this issue is a side-effect of how the Linux network stack works and how library libpcap captures traffic.

https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/1114
https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/CorrectTrafficDump

I hope I've helped.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.